If $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ and $\text{supp}(u) \subset \Omega$ is compact then $u \in W^{2,p}_0(\Omega)$?
In the book Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations from Brezis is proved:
Lemma 9.5: If $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $1 \leq p < +\infty$ and $\text{supp}(u) \subset \Omega$ is compact, then $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$.
I need a version of above Lemma for $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, that is, I wonder if is it true:
Conjecture: If $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, $1 \leq p < +\infty$ and $\text{supp}(u) \subset \Omega$ is compact, then $u \in W^{2,p}_0(\Omega)$.
If this is not the case, what should be the additional hypothesis under which the result would be true? Is there a reference with this kind of result?

In your case, $u \in W^{1, p}$ and $u' \in W^{1, p}$. Does that help?

You can directly use the proof of the Brezis book and extend it to $W^{2,p}$.

@daw, thank you for the answer. Do you think I should put some additional hypothesis?

No additional hypotheses required imho

@HyperbolicPDEfriend, thank you for your answer. I know, by Lemma 9.5, $u \in W^{1,p}0(\Omega)$. I don't know if $\text{supp}(u{x_i}) \subset \Omega$, if this is the case, I would get $u_{x_i} \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$. Still I wouldn't know how to prove that $u \in W^{2,p}_0(\Omega)$.

Well, if $u_{x_i} \in W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$, then automatically $u \in W^{2, p}_0(\Omega)$. Moreover, at the points, where $u$ is $0$, the derivative will also be $0$.

How can I prove that $u_{x_i} \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \implies u \in W^{2,p}_0(\Omega)$? If $v_n \in C^{\infty}0(\Omega)$ is such that $v_n \to u{x_i}$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, how can I get a sequence converging to $u$ in $W^{2,p}(\Omega)$?
